# Visual Studio Code: Updates are disabled because you are running the user-scope installation of Visual Studio Code as Administrator

Tags: administrator, visual-studio-code

I run my Visual Studio Code using "Run as Administrator"

While Visual Studio Code is open I get this message:

> Updates are disabled because you are running the **user-scope** installation of Visual Studio Code **as Administrator**.

The message has a link to "Learn more" [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/windows)

The "Learn more" link gives a similar message, so my issue is clear...

> Note: When running VS Code **as Administrator** in a **user setup** installation, updates will be disabled.

I found these links:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/16p2cdn/how_to_get_around_the_following_updates_are/
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/194818

Just posting a Super User question to compile how to update visual studio code and/or avoid this error...

Answer (score 1):

It's clear I have the **"user-setup installation"** of VS Code. [The "Learn more" link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/windows) explains:

> The user setup does **not** require Administrator privileges to run as the location will be under your user Local AppData (`LOCALAPPDATA`) folder. Since it requires no elevation, the user setup is able to provide a **smoother background update** experience. **This is the preferred way** to install VS Code on Windows.

### System-setup installation

*One solution (as suggested both [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/194818#issuecomment-1748801877) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/16p2cdn/comment/k1ogvay/)) is to use the **system-setup installation** of VS Code instead.*

> The system setup **requires elevation to Administrator privileges** to run and will place the installation under the system's Program Files. The in-product **update flow will also require elevation**, making it **less streamlined than the user setup**. On the other hand, installing VS Code using the system setup means that it will be **available to all users in the system.**

- The system-setup installation requires Admin, which works for me (I "Run as Administrator" anyway!).
- Also the system-setup installation is available to all users (side-effect, this may be a good thing or bad thing depending on your circumstances...)

### Close and re-open VS Code as *non-administrator*

Another solution is simply to close all open VS code instances, then **re-open VS Code as a non-administrator**.

In my case VS Code automatically started updating (check the Help menu; notice the disabled "Installing updates..." message, or if that process is finished, the option might read "Restart to Update")

[image: VS Code help menu, showing a disabled option "Installing updates..."]

### Check for updates (requires one of the above two)

Finally you could try to update manually by checking the Help menu option > "Check for Updates" as suggested [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/setup-overview#_update-cadence).

However, this option is **not available** while you have a user-setup installation and you "Run as Administrator", so if you want to manually Check for Updates, you must use one of the above two approaches.

Of course you could [manually re-install VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) if the other options don't work. More on VS Code's auto-updating here, and [disabling it here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/faq#_how-do-i-opt-out-of-vs-code-autoupdates)

**EDIT**
I agree with @Waggers' comment,

> I understand that I don't **need** to be an administrator to get updates on the user version. I don't understand why being an administrator means I **can't** get automatic updates, that's completely counter-intuitive.

When I check [these](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/1591ace90eeb344fc23f95a9c4f762abb086bd38/src/vs/workbench/contrib/update/browser/update.ts#L212C26-L212C58) [spots](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/1591ace90eeb344fc23f95a9c4f762abb086bd38/src/vs/platform/update/common/update.ts#L60) in VS Code source code where I find the message "Updates are disabled..." and the enum `DisablementReason.RunningAsAdmin`, I don't see comments... maybe if I checked the Git history...

My best guess is this is to prevent anyone who mistakenly thinks that "Running as Administrator" changes the scope of the installation to be more "system-wide" (which it won't, as long as you have the "user-setup installation")

Comment: I understand that I don't *need* to be an administrator to get updates on the user version. I don't understand why being an administrator means I *can't* get automatic updates, that's completely counter-intuitive.

Comment: I agree @Waggers. I know I haven't answered *why* running-as-admin *precludes/prevents* the user-setup installation from updating. Maybe someone else can explain. I did add some links to the VS Code source code and the `DisablementReason.RunningAsAdmin` enum in case I can do more research & find out, later....